# Show div element in HTML that changes with the value in a txt file

Tags: javascript, html

We're trying to make a website in html that shows an alert if the value in a local text file changes to, for example, 1. And if the value changes to 0, we want the alert to not show. We have managed to read from the file, and using php made it show an alert. But we can't make it update without refreshing the page and also not closing the alert if the value changes.

We have javascript code that reads from our text file, and updates without refreshing the page, but right now it just prints the value from the file. We want it to show or hide a div depending on the value in the file.

```
    window.onload = function() {
      var reader = new XMLHttpRequest() || new ActiveXObject('MSXML2.XMLHTTP');
    
      function loadFile() {
        reader.open('get', 'value.txt', true);
        reader.onload = displayContents;
        reader.send(null);
      }
    
      function displayContents() {
        if (reader.readyState == 4) {
          var el = document.getElementById('main');
          el.innerHTML += reader.responseText + "<br>";
          outputData();
        }

      }

      function outputData() {
        var refresh = 2000;
        update = setTimeout(loadFile, refresh);
      }

      loadFile()
    }
```

Comment: So check and see what the response is. Seems like it would be a simple if/else statement

Comment: `if (reader.responseText.trim() === 'XYZ')......`